# Call a method/ handle event in Windows Service from hosted WCF Service

Tags: windows-services, wcf

apologies in advance for this question being dumb, or previously covered. I have researched far and wide but have not found any resources on WCF/ Windows Services that cover this question.

I have a managed Windows Service which is working nicely. Every n (>5) seconds it checks on the status (e.g. memory consumption) of some processes and other Windows services and also does some database logging and raises events where necessary.

I intend to make an ASP.NET website that would allow users to query the status of the processes that the Windows Service is monitoring. Having researched the options it looks like the up-to-date method would be to use a WCF Service, hosted in the Windows Service, to act as intermediary between the ASP.NET website and the Windows Service. Such that, a user could request through the browser a snapshot of the current status of whatever set of processes the Windows Service was monitoring, and have this request and subsequent response  relayed through the WCF service (using named pipes, I think).

So, my difficulty is that there a set of methods and events in the Windows Service for which a single root object exists (let's say MonitorObject). I don't see how the ServiceHost can be instantiated with the reference to MonitorObject so that the WCF Service can call the methods in the Windows Service. I am thinking that perhaps I need to make the Monitor object a shared (I am VB'ing) member of the Windows Service class (that contains OnStart and OnStop) and make all the events shared so that the WCF Service can just access the WindowsService.SharedMonitorObject without needing to be passed the object....

However, I am lost in the subject and am seeking any advice on how best to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going down the right track.  I wouldn't necessarily make the entire `MonitorObject` shared, but you might put a shared method in that object that will return the single root object to the caller.

There is a design pattern called the Singleton Pattern that will help you with this.  Jon Skeet has written an [excellent article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) on some of the things to be aware of when using this pattern in .NET.  His article uses C# for the examples, but [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319108/singleton-pattern-in-vb) a SO question referencing this pattern using VB.

While it's unclear from your description, my guess is that your Windows Service is essentially single-threaded right now.  Just keep in mind that once you add the WCF service, you'll need to make the methods that it references thread-safe.