# Can I shorten the access of my Lazy class without disadvantage

Tags: vb.net

So this is how I would design my Lazy class (From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319108/singleton-pattern-in-vb) SO):

```
Public NotInheritable Class MySingleton
    Private Shared ReadOnly _instance As New Lazy(Of MySingleton)(Function() New _
            MySingleton(), System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication)

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance() As MySingleton
        Get
            Return _instance.Value
        End Get
    End Property

    Private _MyString As String
    Public Property MyString As String
        Get
            Return _MyString
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _MyString = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

To access the _MyString value, I do the following:

```
Dim MyString = MySingleton.Instance.MyString
```

In fact, I always have to type the ".Instance."
Does it have any disadvantage if I design the Property the following way:

```
Public Property MyString As String
    Get
        Return instance._MyString
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        instance._MyString = value
    End Set
End Property
```

So I can access it without always writing the ".Instance."

```
Dim MyString = MySingleton.MyString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can (of course with `Public Shared Property`), but you are losing some of the benefits from singleton over static classes.

Lets say you have another class `MyWorker`

```
Public Class MyWorker

    Public Sub Work(instance as MySingleton)
       Dim value as String = instance.MyString
       ' Do something ...
    End Sub

End Class
```

I would not do this. This may not look like a big issue, but on the long run you have a tight coupling in your code base and a hard time mocking your class for unit testing, one of the reasons for using singeltons over static classes in the first place.

I often use this approach, when accessing Singelton values mutiple times:

```
Dim instance as MySingelton = MySingelton.Value
If instance.MyString = "something" Then
    instance.MyString = "something else"
End If
```

much cleaner approach.