# sql transactions multiple classes vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, class, transactions

Using Visual Studio 2013, VB.NET w/ SQL Server (various versions from 2008 forward)

In my VB.NET project I have created classes to represent the major entities in my project - for example, cSalesOrder, cSalesOrderDetail, cPacklist, etc etc. Each of those classes contain various methods to perform basic tasks like Save, Update, Load, etc.

In my most recent project I have to ensure that all processes succeed before saving, so I'm using SQL Transactions. My question is how to best handle those transactions across multiple objects which manage their own data processes.

Here's what I'm doing now. When I need to fire off the process, I use a code block like this to create my Connection, Transaction and Command objects:

```
Using con As New SQLConnection(MyConnectString)
  con.Open
  Using trn As SQLTransaction = trn.BeginTransaction
    Using cmd As New SQLCommand
      cmd.Connection = con
      cmd.Transaction = trn
         <code here>
    End Using
  End Using
End Using

(In the <code here> section I would create my objects and run the process.)
```

In each class, I've declared a "cmd" object. For example, in my cSalesOrder class I have this line:

```
Dim cmd As SQLCommand
```

And then when I instance that class, I pass in the cmd object I created in the block above:

```
Dim so As New cSalesOrder
so.cmd = cmd
so.Load
```

Then the various methods in my class use that "cmd" object to perform their tasks.

I've tried using temporary DataTables to hold my data before writing, but I've run into issues with PK violations. The systems can be very high volume, and it would not be unusual for a user to insert a new record in one of the affected tables before my process completes.

Is there a better way to do this to ensure that all of my classes use the same transaction?

Comment: IMO, the command object doesn't belong in your classes. Wrap your business logic in `TransactionScope`. Research the Unit Of Work (UoW) pattern.

Comment: TransactionScope was the ticket. It's very easy to use, and works perfectly to encapsulate the business logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the 'singleton' pattern to ensure that all classes can only access one static instance of your transaction.

If you have multiple types of transactions that are completely encapsulated and would not create pk violations within other transactions if they ran at the same time, you could create multiple types of objects following the singleton pattern.  For example: SalesOrderTransaction, PurchaseOrderTransaction, etc.

[singleton pattern in vb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319108/singleton-pattern-in-vb)